# A way to add set target markers through quick slots?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

To set a target marker above a mob today, you have to right click on the portrait and select the icon through a popup menu.

Is there a quicker way to do this? I'd like to be able to do this through the quick slots.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Currently this isn't possible. There's also no macro or scripting capability, so you can't put anything on the bars that you can't just drag there, and sadly, setting icons isn't in the keybinds menu under prefs either.

However, as **DavidYell** notes in the comments, there are a number of 'social' and other toy items that can be used to achieve a similar effect.

Comment: What about the republic target marker? It's a social item which when used puts a marker on a target, perhaps because it's an item it can be placed in a quickslot. They cost 500c from a social vendor.

Comment: Good suggestion - the target marker item does indeed work from a quickslot.

Comment: Yes, but there is only the republic/empire marker, right? That gives just one mark. Better than nothing, for sure, but I'd like two markers. (kill and crowd control)

Answer (score 3):

From [this Reddit thread](http://www.reddit.com/r/swtor/comments/p2tsl/marking_targets_with_a_g500_mouse/), it's possible if you have a mouse (or other peripheral) with programmable buttons to bind <kbd>\</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> to one of the buttons to mark a target more efficiently.

In the Redditor's example he uses the Logitech SetPoint software with a G500 mouse (there's also a link to doing it with a G15 keyboard and binding `\mark 1 [Enter]`, `\mark 2 [Enter]` etc to keyboard buttons).

Beware though that this is borderline (though harmless IMO) macro-ing, and may be frowned on (or worse) by the powers that be. The relevant [TOS section](http://www.swtor.com/legalnotices/rulesofconduct) is:

> You may not use macros, add-ons or other stored rapid keystrokes,
>   "dupes," "cheats" or other patterns of play that facilitate
>   acquisition of items, currency, objects, character attributes, rank or
>   status at an accelerated rate.

IMHO (IANAL) this counts as "*stored rapid keystrokes*" but doesn't count as, "*patterns of play that facilitate acquisition of items, currency, objects, character attributes, rank or status at an accelerated rate*".

Answer (score 2):

If you've got the Collector's Edition or the Digital Deluxe Edition (which you can [upgrade a standard version to](https://account.swtor.com/user/digitalupgrade)), the [Training Droid](http://www.torhead.com/item/cRDiHaX/training-droid) can be added to a quickslot and deployed to spin around a target's head. Can't remember what the cooldown on that is, but its not a long one.

Answer (score 2):

Under Key Bindings, Targeting section, you can assign hot keys to all 8 of the target markers

- Orange Blaster
- Green Saber
- Blue Shield
- Red Flame
- Yellow Reticle
- Cyan Lightning
- Gold Star
- Purple Gear

That's what I use for the top 3... using <kbd>[</kbd> <kbd>]</kbd> <kbd>\</kbd> keys since they're a little out of the way but I don't need them often.